# Modifying/changing lines in a text document using php

Tags: php

I want to modify certain lines in a .txt files depending on a condition.

CODE : (php)

```
 $sur = "newsur";
 $nume = "newname";

 $contacte = [];
    if (file_exists("Contacts.txt"))
        {
        $find = fopen("Contacts.txt", "r");
        while ($Row = fgets($find))
            {
            $line = explode(";", $Row);
            $contact = ['Surname' => $date[0], 'Name' => $date[1], ];
            if ( $contact['Surname'] == "nume1" && $contact['Name'] == "nume2" )
                {

                $contact['Surname']=$sur;
                $contact['Name']=$nume;

                }
                $contacte[]=$contact;
            }
            fclose ($find);
        } 




$file = fopen("Contacts.txt", "w"); 
{
 if ($file){
foreach($contacte as $c){
 fwrite ($file,"{$c['Surname']};{$c['Name']} \n");
                       }
           }
}
fclose ( $file );
?>
```

My file has 2 rows

nume1;nume2

nume3;nume4

I'm pretty sure I messed up at the array declaration and getting the `.txt` files elements as it will say I have unidentified variables. After execution, on  this line

```
$contact = ['Surname' => $date[0], 'Name' => $date[1], ];
```

I'll get 4 unidentified variable error (hence I have 2 rows, 2 elements on each), my documents content will be deleted and only the ";" will be added again.

Comment: Did you mean `$Row[0]` and `$Row[1]`? There is no `$date`.

Comment: Changing $date to $row it's solving the errors, but i don't get what i want. As i said, my .txt document has 2 rows, nume1;nume2 and nume3;nume4. What i want to do is change just specific rows(like in my code, the one that has nume1;nume2). As i said, there are no more errors, but what i get is : the first row is   n;u and even the second one changed to n;u as well.

Comment: Actually you want `$line[0]` and `$line[1]`

Comment: I changed it to line later. It will add a new row after my selected row, but it won't change it. It will just add new rows.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified quite a bit. Since you're replacing lines where both of the strings on either side of the semicolon delimiter equal certain values, you don't need to explode each line on semicolon and check the separate parts, you can just match the entire line.

```
$sur = "newsur";
$nume = "newname";

$contacts = [];
if (file_exists('Contacts.txt')) {
   $rows = file('Contacts.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);              // get all the rows
   foreach ($rows as $row) {
      $contacts[] = ($row == 'nume1;nume2') ? "$sur;$nume" : $row;   // replace matching rows
   }
}
file_put_contents('Contacts.txt', implode("\n", $contacts));         // write results
```

Comment: It sure works. But in my original code i have 8 elements on a row and i want to test only 2(if they match). That's why i exploded each line on semicolon. Now i got rid of errors, but i sure don't get what i want. Also because i want to be able to edit certain elements of a row(e.g i have name,surname,phone number,email..and some others), not the entire row.

Comment: Or maybe i'll leave it like that. I can find a purpose for the whole row too. And one other question if i'm at it. Can I delete the row with your method?

Comment: Sure, depending on your criteria for deletion, just don't add it to the `$contacts` array.